# Facebook Login product has a grey checkmark

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create an app with a Facebook Login button. After I created the app in Facebook Developers panel, I found the Facebook Login product has a grey checkmark (please see the screenshot below). I have another app where this checkmark is green.

Does it mean it's currently under review or do I need to some more stuff to set it up? There's no reference that I can find about the meaning of this icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: it probably means that the product has been set up but you haven't used it at least once. Once I use it in code, it becomes green.

Answer (score 0):

After Lot of Trial And Error I got solution which is given below

1. goto Products FaceBook Login
2. settings->Valid OAuth Redirect URIs
3. If you have added [www.abc.org](http://www.abc.org) and [www.abc.org/auth/login/facebook/callback](http://www.abc.org/auth/login/facebook/callback)
4. you should also add abc.org and abc.org/auth/login/facebook.callback

It will become Green Automatically.